# On google autocomplite change set value to public object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have public object `location` and on callback I need to set values to that object....

```
public location: any;

ngOnInit() {
        let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((this.search.nativeElement), {types: ['(cities)']});

        //add event listener to google autocomplete and capture address input
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        });

}
```

So I need place from `addListener` to assign to public variable location... How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your object instance to another variable, because "this" is defined in some google context in the callback.

I do it like this:

```js
public location: any;

ngOnInit() {
        let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((this.search.nativeElement), {types: ['(cities)']});

        //add event listener to google autocomplete and capture address input
        
        let self = this;
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            self.location = autocomplete.getPlace();
        });

}
```